# Los primeros 25 números, ¿por qué no imprime el resultado en la consola?

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de hacer un código que me imprima los primeros 25 números primos. Lo inicialicé con 100, pero cuando lo imprimo en la consola no me aparece nada. No sé cuál será el problema o si hay algo que me hará falta para añadir al código

```java
    public class MainClass1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] primes = new int[100];
            
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
                primes[i] = i;
                count = 0;
        
                for(int j = i; j < primes.length; j++) {
                    if(primes[i] % j == 0) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if(count == 2) {
                    System.out.print(primes[i] + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Comment: a) Estás perdiendo la posición 0 del array `primes`; de entrada sólo vas a poder ingresar 99 elementos. b) no hay 99 primos entre 1 y 100, entonces el punto a no va a hacer fallar el programa. c) arrancas asignando en el array todos los valores que vas iterando (1,2,3,...) y el segundo ciclo comienza en j=i (que es la posición que acabas de asignar), así que siempre vas a validar UNA vez contra el número mismo, el count no llega a 2 nunca y no imprimes nada. d) no llegas a 100, entonces el punto a no hace estallar el programa. FIn de la ejecución. Revisa cómo hacerle depuración a tus programas

Comment: Además de lo que comenta Alfabravo, te sugiero revisar la teória de como determinar los números primos: https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/09/20/java-numero-primo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para determinar si el número es primo, la iteración debe iniciar desde el número 2, ya que 0 no es primo y el número 1 sólo tiene un divisor, que es él mismo, tampoco es considerado como número primo, debemos dividir por todos los números primos menores ordenados ascendentemente.

```
class MainClass1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        int[] primes = new int[100];
         
        int count = 0;
        //for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++) { 
        for(int i = 2; i < 100; i++) { //* inicia en 2
            primes[i] = i;
            count = 0;
            
            for(int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                //if(primes[i] % j == 0) {
                if(i % j == 0) {                
                    count++;
                    //System.out.print(primes[i] + " ");
                }
            }
            if(count == 0) { //* El contador debe ser igual a 0
                System.out.print(primes[i] + " ");
            }
            
        }
        // System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Esta es una [tabla de números primos](https://www.superprof.es/apuntes/escolar/matematicas/aritmetica/divisibilidad/numeros-primos.html)  para que compares el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Modifiqué tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
public class MainClass1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {       
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
                count = 0;
        
                for(int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                
                    if((i % j) == 0) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if(count == 0) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Había los siguientes problemas en tu código:

1. `j` empieza en `i` y va hasta la longitud de `primes`, que siempre tendrá `i - 1` elementos, por lo tanto el `for` más interno siempre se ejecuta cero veces.
2. Parece que querías ver cuándo el módulo da cero para todos los anteriores, pero eso no determinaría si el número es un primo, a menos que llegaras hasta el propio número `i`.
3. Aunque no usas la lista `primes` al final ésta tiene todos los números entre 1 y 100, aunque no todos son primos.

Para simplificar el código, eliminé la lista `primes`, porque no la utilizabas en realidad. También modifiqué la condición para verificar si el número es un primo (que haya cero divisores entre `2` e `i - 1`). Asimismo, hago que `i` empiece en `2` para no incluir al `1` como primo.